# Req.body is empty on post and put request in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

The server file is

```
'use strict';

var express        = require('express');
var compression    = require('compression');
var configDB       = require('./config/database');
var mongoose       = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var logger         = require('morgan');
var path           = require('path');
var app            = express();

var deliveries     = require('./routes/deliveries');

var mongoString;
if (process.env.MONGOLAB_URI) {
 console.log('Now in HEROKU');
 mongoString = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
} else {
 mongoString = configDB.dev;
 console.log('In dev mongo', mongoString);
}

mongoose.connect(mongoString);
mongoose.connection;

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api/deliveries', deliveries);

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
 var host = 'localhost';
 var port = server.address().port;
 console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I don't know what is wrong with the server setup.
Making a post and put request has been a pain.
I have been battling with this for the past 1 hour. Any help to what I am doing wrong.

The route file is

```
router.put('/cancel/:id', function(req, res) {
 deliveries.cancel(req, res);
});

deliveriesControllerActions.cancelDelivery = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers['content-type']);
  if (!(util.isEmpty(req.query))) {
   req.body = req.query;
  }

 var deliveryid = req.params.deliveryid;
 var userid = req.body.userid;
 var cancelStatus = {
  status: true,
  timestamp: Date.now()
 };

if (!util.verifyInputFields(userid, deliveryid)) {
  util.sendErrResponse(res, 404, 'userid is empty');
} else {
 Delivery.findById(deliveryid)
   .exec(function(err, deliveryObject) {
    if (deliveryObject) {
      if (deliveryObject.cancelled_by_sender.status || deliveryObject.cancelled_by_admin.status || deliveryObject.cancelled_by_receiver.status) {
        saveUpdatedDelivery(res, userid, deliveryObject);
      } else {
        deliveryObject.status = deliveryRequestCancelledStatus;
        deliveryObject.cancelled_by_admin = cancelStatus;
        saveUpdatedDelivery(res, userid, deliveryObject);
      }
    } else if (err) {
      util.sendErrResponse(res, 404, err);
    }
  });
 }
```

}

Comment: What is in `req.headers['content-type']`?

Comment: Posting the routes would probably be a good idea.

Comment: @mscdex `req.headers['content-type']` = `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @adeneo i have updated the question with the route file

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not sending the appropriate type of data to the server. You're submitting something other than `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (`text/plain` evidently). Either the data itself (and `Content-Type`) is not correct, or the `Content-Type` header needs to be set appropriately.

Comment: I do not understand that as I am sending a data from a button click and my angularjs service is `cancel: function(id, userId) {
        console.log("userId: ", userId);
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.put('/api/deliveries/cancel/' + id, userId)
        .success(function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      },` @mscdex

Comment: can you be more explicit please ?

Comment: Assuming `userId` is not an object (e.g. a string or number), most likely `$http.put()` is not sending it as JSON since it's a simple primitive value. If you want to send a string as JSON, you will probably need to override the request's `transformRequest` or similar and force `JSON.stringify()` usage. Otherwise, just do something like this instead: `$http.put(...., { userId: userId });`. Then on the server side you should be able to see `req.body.userId`.

Comment: I implemented that before and I have also tried it again. Still not working